# Get interval in milliseconds

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, intervals

I have a procedure that contains code like this:

```
processStart := current_timestamp;
-- run statement(s)
processEnd := current_timestamp;
elapsed := processEnd - processStart;
raise notice 'My Statement, elapsed time: %', elapsed;
```

The idea is, I want to get the amount of time it takes for a statement or collection of statements to run.

The problem is, this returns `00:00:00` for subsecond elapsed times.  I really want to see the milliseconds.  How can I do this?

There's questions and answers about using `EXTRACT` and `EPOCH`, but this seems to be at the "second" level, and that is not granular enough for my purposes.

**UPDATE**

Using @twn08's answer, I ultimately arrived at the following solution:

I declared the following variables:

```
declare
    processStart timestamp;
    elapsed numeric(18,3);
    processFinish timestamp;
```

then, prior to starting the process:

```
processStart := clock_timestamp();
```

after the process was finished, I ran this:

```
processFinish := clock_timestamp();
elapsed := cast(extract(epoch from (processFinish - processStart)) as numeric(18,3));
raise notice 'My Statement, elapsed time: % ms', elapsed;
```

this worked swimmingly.

Comment: You can extract milliseconds: `SELECT EXTRACT(MILLISECONDS FROM Now());`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
with t as
 (select
    Now() as tend, 
    Now() - interval '10 seconds 552 milliseconds' as tstart
 )

select
  extract('epoch' from tend)  - extract('epoch' from tstart) 
from 
  t
```

Note:

For version 9.0+ you can read in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html) the following example:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40.12-08');
Result: 982384720.12
```

Before 9.0 [there is](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40-08');
Result: 982384720
```

Based on this it is not entirely clear whether my example will work prior to version 9.0

Comment: While this answer was not very clear, it did help me figure out what I needed to do.  See my edited question for the final result.

Comment: FYI: `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t)` definitely works in 8.4.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a one-liner to calculate the elapsed time in milliseconds from a past TIMESTAMP to now():

```
SELECT ROUND((EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM now()) - EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp())) * 1000) AS "replication_lag (ms)";
```

The above example calculates the replication lag between a primary and standby PostgreSQL server, so simply replace `pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp()` with your TIMESTAMP.

To see what it's doing a bit more clearly:

```
SELECT
    ROUND ((
        EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM now()) -
        EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp())
    ) * 1000)
AS "replication_lag (ms)";
```

Output:

```
 replication_lag (ms) 
----------------------
                  562
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on @TomasGreif's answer, I made a little datediff function in case you need to do millisecond datediffs often:

```
create function datediff_ms(timestamptz, timestamptz) returns INTEGER as
$$
    begin
        return (EXTRACT('epoch' from $2) - EXTRACT('epoch' from $1)) * 1000;
    end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Usage:

```
select datediff_ms(time1, time2)
from sometables;
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can extract the epoch from the interval, which might make the syntax a bit more concise.

```
select extract('epoch' from (t2-t1))
```

versus

```
select extract('epoch' from t2) - extract('epoch' from t1)
```